# Which of the versions of Counter Strike: Condition Zero is the latest?

Tags: version-differences, counter-strike-condition-zero

I watched some videos on YouTube recently featuring *Counter Strike: Condition Zero*, but I'm not sure which shows the latest version of the game.

There's no major differences between them, but bot/weapon skins and sound effects have minor differences, but not in a way that someone could tell one was newer over another.

All are shown as 'Condition Zero' and have same Tour of Duties and UI/UX.

#### Game 1 screenshots:

[image: desert map with 'Portal' on a billboard]
[image: Inside shot, 'Rescue the hostages for money']
[image: outside with 3 terrorists]

#### Game 2 screenshots:

[image: outside sandstone walls]

#### Game 3 screenshots:

[image: end-of-match scoreboard]
[image: outside sandstone walls]

Comment: Portal on the wall on de_dust, which was released almost a decade after the game in question. That's interesting. I'd say they're the same version, just mixed up 1.6 and CZ games or models.

Comment: It would also be convenient to post your sources, as that would already proof it's not from after the upload date.

Comment: Like @Joachim states, it would be helpful to have the actual video links. 1) we can look at the upload date to get an approximation, 2) we can scrub through the footage ourselves looking for other unique things.

Answer (score 4):

Game 2 is standard Counter Strike (latest version 1.6).

Game 1 and 3 are the same, which is Counter Strike :Condition Zero.

You can tell the difference by a couple of things.

First, on game 3, the name is clearly indicated on the score screenshot.
Game 3 and 1 shares the same updated player models for the red bandana terrorist.

You can differentiate 1.6 from CZ by the little location written under the minimap.

And to answer your question, Condition Zero is the most recent of the two. CS is 2000 while CZ is 2004.

Comment: This doesn't help as all three of them are Condition Zero games. If you've read correctly the details.

Comment: @Vikas Sorry, when I answered that info was not included in the question. Also, you say that the games are similar apart from the models and a couple of UI things.

Comment: That's the main difference between 1.6 and Conditikn Zero (CZ being just a reskinned 1.6 with bot support added). That's why it didn't sell that well at the time it came out.

Comment: _CZ being just a reskinned 1.6 with bot support added_ Wrong.

Comment: @Vikas It doesn't seem far from the truth...  That seems to be basically all they did.

Comment: Well, they added official bots, a "solo mode" which is basically a series of levels with objectives. I also remember that, by buying CZ, you would get access to a preview of CS Source (with only Dust2 playable) ... but I can't find more info about that online.

Answer (score -1):

They look really similar, I'm assuming that they are all the same game, just played on different maps or reskinned to the YouTubers liking. That's the most plausible answer as all the "games" look and feel all too similar.

Comment: Thanks but I expect a canonical answer.